# Create DefaultTable from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, renderer

how can I create a DefaultTable from my ArrayList:

```
public class FileModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel{

    List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

    String titles[] = new String[] { "File Name", "Pages", "Media Box Height", "Media Box Width", "Trim Box Height",
            "Trim Box Width", "Path", "Error" };
    Class<?> types[] = new Class[] { String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Integer.class,  Integer.class, String.class, String.class };
```

I want to use it for a color renderer, because at the moment the renderer just colors "Strings"...
The DefaultModel should look like:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
```

My current Colorrenderer looks so:

```
    public class ColorRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final int STATUS_COL = 7;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int col) {

        Component component = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        String type = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7);
        if ("Error" == type) {
            component.setBackground(Color.RED);
            component.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        } else if (isSelected) {
            component.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            component.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());

        } else {
            component.setBackground(table.getBackground());
            component.setForeground(table.getForeground());
        }

        return component;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just few hints that hopefully will help you to solve your problem.

1) A common mistake is asking the model for the first row values to retrieve the column class. That is simply ***wrong***. What if the model is empty? We'll get a `NullPointerException`. Since we know the model (we are modeling it) we are perfectly capable to return the appropriate class. For example:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        // return getValueAt(0, column).getClass(); NO! Never do we have to do this.
        switch (column) {
            case 0: return String.class;
            case 1: return Integer.class;
            ...
            case 7: return String.class;
                default: throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(column);
    }
};
```

---

2) In `ColorRenderer` class there's a mistake comparing strings:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
    ...
    if ("Error" == type) { // This should be "Error".equals(type)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Besides, `row` variable represents the row index in the *view* not the *model* so this line:

```
String type = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 7);
```

Might not return the expected value if the table is sorted. You need to convert the index like this:

```
int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
String type = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(modelIndex, 7);
```

---

3) About this question: *"how can I create a DefaultTable from my ArrayList:"*

If you want to implement your own table model instead of using `DefaultTableModel`, see the options examined in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496985/working-with-several-custom-table-models-avoiding-repetitive-code).

### Edit

> *The only think is that only **Strings** are colored...But I have 4 Columns with **Integers**, they still keep in table background color.*

The answer to this depends on how do you set the default renderer but I suspect you are doing this:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new ColorRenderer());
```

Which works for `String` class but not for `Integer` class because the second one has a default renderer supplied by the table and has to be explicitely replaced, while the first one doesn't. For a complete and better explanation about renderer/editors selection see [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). For practical purposes just do this:

```
TableCellRenderer renderer = new ColorRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, renderer); // This will work for Integer, Double, Float...
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
```

Comment: thank you very much. I've implemented the second point of your solution, so I didn't need the first anymore. It works perfectly now. The only think is that only **Strings** are colored...But I have 4 Columns with **Integers**, they still keep in table background color -.-

Comment: wow this is awesome! thank you :-) Now I'm really a step further

Comment: You are welcome :) If this answer is good enough for you then don't forget to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). @okaisan1