# AbstractTableModel Help in name Columns sql

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I have a subclass of `AbstractTableModel` and a `JFrame` to display the data from my table, ran over and the only error that appears instead of the column names appear A, B, C

What am I doing wrong?

Here are my classes

```
    package Biblioteca;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TabelaAlunos extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ArrayList linhas = null;
    private String[] colunas = {"id_aluno", "nome_aluno", "matricula", "telefone", "email", "sexo"};

    public TabelaAlunos(ArrayList lin, String[] col) {

        setColunas(col);
        setLinhas(lin);

    }

    public ArrayList getLinhas() {
        return linhas;
    }

    public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados) {
        linhas = dados;
    }

    public String[] getColunas() {
        return colunas;
    }

    public void setColunas(String[] nomes) {
        colunas = nomes;
    }
@Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colunas.length;
    }
@Override
    public int getRowCount() {

        return linhas.size();
    }
 @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return colunas[columnIndex];

    }
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int columnIndex) {

        Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(numLin);
        return linha[columnIndex];
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in this method:

```
    public String getColomnName(int numCol) {
        return colunas[numCol];
    }
```

It should be (note the *u* instead of *o*):

```
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int numCol) {
        return colunas[numCol];
    }
```

This is why `@Override` annotation is important when we are subclassing and overriding methods. If you include this annotation in your actual code it shouldn't compile because `getColomnName(...)` is not defined in parent class.

The same principle applies for all these methods:

- `getColumnCount()`
- `getRowCount()`
- `getValueAt(int row, int column)`

---

### Edit

Based on your update your table model looks just fine. I've made an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using your table model and it all worked as expected. Check out the questions' [third revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26890337/3), you don't use `TabelaAlunos` table model but `TabelaLivros` instead, so it's probably the issue is in that table model.

You might also consider wrap your data using POJO's to model business data and implement a table model like exemplified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496985/working-with-several-custom-table-models-avoiding-repetitive-code). There are advanced alternatives shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496994/1795530) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26498858/1795530). Also see [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) by Rob Camick.

Finally, please see the example below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        String[] header = {"id_aluno", "nome_aluno", "matricula", "telefone", "email", "sexo"};
        ArrayList<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Object[] {1, "Fernando", "1234567890", "1234-567890", "email@example.com", "M"});

        TableModel model = new TabelaAlunos(data, header);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TabelaAlunos extends AbstractTableModel {

        private ArrayList linhas;
        private String[] colunas;

        public TabelaAlunos(ArrayList lin, String[] col) {
            setColunas(col);
            setLinhas(lin);
        }

        public ArrayList getLinhas() {
            return linhas;
        }

        public void setLinhas(ArrayList dados) {
            linhas = dados;
        }

        public String[] getColunas() {
            return colunas;
        }

        public void setColunas(String[] nomes) {
            colunas = nomes;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return colunas.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {

            return linhas.size();
        }
        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
            return colunas[columnIndex];

        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int numLin, int columnIndex) {
            Object[] linha = (Object[]) getLinhas().get(numLin);
            return linha[columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Example]

Comment: Already did it, but always appear in A, B,C,D in name columns

Comment: That outcome suggests that the default implementation of `getColumnName(int columnIndex)` inherited from `AbstractTableModel` is the one being called, not yours. So I guess you still having issues on overriding that method correctly in order to return the approapriate column name. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26890337/edit) your question with your table model code updated. @FernandoTricksCombo

Comment: like this? but the name remains the same

Comment: Please see my edit. Hopefully you can make it work now @FernandoTricksCombo

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helped you to solve the problem pelase don't forget to [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). @FernandoTricksCombo