# How to set Values from JTable to Text Area in Harvard Referencing Format

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

I'm working on a **Bibliography Generator Application** and I want the values from my `JTable` to display in a `textarea` in **Hardvard Referencing Format**.

This is my code to get and print the values:

```
for (int row = 0; row < CitationTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
            JournalCitation js = new JournalCitation();

            js.setAuthorFirstName((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 1));
            js.setAuthorLastName((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 2));
            js.setYearPublished((int) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 3));
            js.setTitle((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 4));
            js.setVolumeNo((int) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 5));
            js.setIssueNo((int) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 6));
            js.setPagesUsed((int) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 7));
            js.setDoi((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 8));
            js.setDatabaseLocation((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 9));
            js.setUrl((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 10));
            js.setAccessDate((String) CitationTable.getValueAt(row, 11));

            System.out.println(js.getAuthorFirstName() + js.getAuthorLastName() + js.getYearPublished() + js.getTitle() + js.getVolumeNo() + js.getIssueNo() + js.getPagesUsed() + js.getDoi() + js.getDatabaseLocation() + js.getUrl() + js.getAccessDate());


        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me a lot.
I am gonna try using DataObjectTableModel sounds more efficient.

Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#format(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method in order to generate the text you want to display in your text area with the desired format. For example:

```java
String text = String.format("%1s, %2s (%3s) %4s"
                  , js.getAuthorLastName().toUpperCase()
                  , js.getAuthorFirstName().toUpperCase()
                  , js.getYearPublished()
                  , js.getTitle()
);
textArea.setText(text);
```

This format will produce something like this:

```
SOMMERVILLE, IAN (2011) Software engineering
```

**Note:** I don't know the Harvard Referencing System but I hope you get the idea.

**Note 2:** `JTextArea` doesn't support text format such as bold or italics. You might want to use [JEditorPane or JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) to fulfill this requirement if needed.

#### Off-topic

Instead of mapping-back the table's cells to a `JournalCitation` object manually, you might consider use a custom table model that allows you to hold objects of this class. Something like [DataObjectTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496994/1795530) or Rob Camick's [RowTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) / [ListTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/) / [BeanTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) might be helpful to avoid reinventing the wheel.