# Removing a row from a JTable using AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, abstracttablemodel

I have a `JTable`. This table is using a custom model that I designed; the custom model is `extends AbstractTableModel`. I have a button which enables a user to delete a selected/highlighted row.

I have tried this code but its giving me a class cast exception -

```
myTableModel cannot be cast to DefaultTableModel.
```

Below is the code.

```
DefaultTableModel model =  (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        model.removeRow(table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow()));
        model.fireTableDataChanged();`
```

I have searched the web but it is always `DefaultTableModel` - but I have `AbstarctTableModel`.

How do we solve this?

Comment: Please show your custom model, if it's not too big.

Comment: method fireTableDataChanged is implemented in DefaultTableModel, then there isn't reason to call that twice,  fireTableDataChanged reseting all custom methods (rendere and editor too), read AbstractTableModels API, there is method for remove row and with proper notifier not  fireTableDataChanged

Comment: *"I have searched the web but it is always `DefaultTableModel` - but I have `AbstarctTableModel`."*  There's a good reason for that, of which this is an example.  The `DefaultTableModel` has this functionality implemented (and without known bugs).  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: I took the liberty to roll back your extensive edits after your problem had been solved. Please don't invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *I have tried this code but its giving me a class cast exception -
>   myTableModel cannot be cast to DefaultTableModel.*

The error is pretty self-explanatory: given you provide the table with your own table model, then `table.getModel()` won't ever return a `DefaultTableModel` instance.

> How do we solve this?

By down-casting `table.getModel()` to the appropriate class (your class). Then call the method you provided to remove a row from your table model. For example:

```
int modelRowIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
MyTableModel model = (MyTableModel)table.getModel();
model.removeRowFromMyModel(modelRowIndex);
```

See a complete example of a custom table model extending from `AbstractTableModel` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26496985/1795530).

#### Off-topic

We never should call any of `fireXxx()` methods explicitely from the outside. Those are intended to be called internally by `AbstractTableModel` subclasses when needed. IMHO those should be `protected` and not `public`, to avoid use them incorrectly. But for some reason I'm not aware of they made them `public`.

Comment: 1+ `. IMHO those should be protected and not public, to avoid use them incorrectly.` good point, that would make our lives easier ;)

Comment: @dic 19 I have followed the model you have shown me, but its giving me an error as shown in the edited question. How do we resolve this error?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but even with downcasting, you won't be able to solve the problem because you wouldn't still have access to the method `removeRow(int rowIndex)` from `DefaultTableModel`. Are you suggesting that he implements his own method to remove the desired row?

Comment: @JesseJames Hi there, yes it is actually stated by the OP: *This table is using a custom model that I designed; the custom model is extends AbstractTableModel*