# Explicitly writing a Class for inserting Data into JTable Swing

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, defaulttablemodel

In my Application i wrote a class which inserts data into JTable.

App have two Entities 1: Category 2: Product

For Category I have written this class . When i want to show data in JTable i call any method from this class according to situation.

```
public class InsertDataToTable {

public void insertCategoriesToTable(JTable tableObject,ArrayList<CategoryEntity> getCategories) {

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) categoryTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    for (CategoryEntity category : getCategories) {
        int id = category.getId();
        String categoryName = category.getCategoryName();
        model.insertRow(categoryTable.getRowCount(), new Object[]{id, categoryName});
    }

}

public void insertSingleCategory(JTable tableObject,CategoryEntity category){
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) categoryTable.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);     
    int id=category.getId();
    String categoryName=category.getCategoryName(); 
    model.insertRow(categoryTable.getRowCount(), new Object[]{id, categoryName});
}

}
```

Now I want to make this class General so that I can pass either category object or product object and It Inserts data to table.

Confusion for me is in

```
public void insertCategoriesToTable(JTable tableObject,ArrayList<CategoryEntity> getCategories)
```

What should i pass instead of ArrayList so that i can call both methods for both  Entities (Category and Product).

I don't want to write same class with little changes for Product Entity.

Comment: you are writing about a 'product object' but i can't find that in the code. What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider writing a custom `TableModel` implementation that allows you to work with domain objects, either `Category` or `Product` or whatever entity you need.

Take a look to these topics:

- [Working with several custom table models avoiding repetitive code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26496985/1795530)
- [Rob Camick's Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/)

In this way you can add / delete / update domain objects directly to/from the `TableModel` without any other class: the `JTable` to which the table model is attached to will be repainted automatically on `TableModelEvent`'s.

Even if you insist in writing a specific class to do the insertions it could be something like this where `T` is the type of the entity you want to instert into your table model (not too much benefits though):

```
public class InsertDataToTable {

    public static <T> void insertToTable(JTable table, List<T> domainObjects) {
        DataObjectTableModel<T> model = (DataObjectTableModel<T>) table.getModel();
        model.clearTableModelData();
        for (T domainObject : domainObject) {
           model.addDataObject(domainObject);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void insertSingleObject(JTable table, T domainObject){
        DataObjectTableModel<T> model = (DataObjectTableModel<T>) table.getModel();
        model.clearTableModelData();
        model.addDataObject(domainObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot and please will you tell me What i s DataObjectTableModel there is no import for  it.

Comment: You are welcome. `DataObjectTableModel` is the class you'll find in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26496994/1795530) to the first link I've included. Please read the entire post and you'll see it's actually what you are looking for. @MuhammadDanishKhan

Comment: it throwing class cast exception       javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel cannot be cast to app.CommonClass.DataObjectTableModel

Comment: Make sure to set a new DataObjectTableModel instance to your JTable *before* inserting anything on it (by default the table model of a JTable is DefaultTableModel) @MuhammadDanishKhan